# Charging a user via Stripe and depositing money into another users account

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, payment

I have a web application that is basically a store. User's post items to sell, other users purchase them. This is the first time I am using the Stripe API and I need to charge a buyer's credit card (either a customer or just from the stripe token) and then deposit it into the sellers account. I see in the documentation, how to charge the card such as

```
var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;

var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
  currency: "usd",
  source: stripeToken,
  description: "Example charge",
  metadata: {'order_id': '6735'}
}, function(err, charge) {
  if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
    // The card has been declined
  }
});
```

But I am completely confused about on how to deposit the money into the seller's bank account? Do I need the user's bank account info? debit card? Do I make them a customer in my stripe account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) to accept payments on behalf of others.

You can find the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). In a nutshell, Connect can be used with [standalone accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts) (which are full-featured Stripe accounts just like yours) and [managed accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts) (which are "account-like" entities that only exist within your own account).

Which you should use depends on where you are located (managed accounts aren't available everywhere yet) and your exact needs. [This article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/considerations-for-platforms-using-connect) has some information that will help you choose.

You then need to decide if you're going to charge [directly on the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-directly):

```
var destination = 'acct_...'; // ID of the destination account
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
  currency: "usd",
  source: stripeToken,
  description: "Example charge",
  metadata: {'order_id': '6735'}
}, {stripe_account: destination},
function(err, charge) {
  ...
```

or [through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform):

```
var destination = 'acct_...'; // ID of the destination account
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
  currency: "usd",
  source: stripeToken,
  description: "Example charge",
  metadata: {'order_id': '6735'},
  destination: destination
}, function(err, charge) {
  ...
```

Comment: does this mean my web application user need stripe accounts?

Comment: If they need to receive funds, yes. If managed accounts are available (i.e. if you're based in the US and Canada), you can make the entire experience very transparent -- aside from agreeing to the Stripe's ToS, managed accounts never interact directly with Stripe, everything goes through the platform (i.e. you).